# How to manage discovery and composition as 2 separate concerns?

Tags: c#, .net, mef, composition

I have set up an assembly catalog:

```
  private CompositionContainer GetContainer() {
     // initialize directory info
     ExtensionDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(settings.ExtensionsPath);
     // directory catalog
     var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(ExtensionDirectory.FullName);

     return new CompositionContainer(dirCatalog);
  }
```

The contents of the container will load up all the assemblies in the directory as expected. I do not want to actually compose anything yet because I have constructors that will be injected with dependencies.

What I want to do is use the `AssemblyCatalog` as a repository; query for a specific export, pass the constructor dependency, then compose *only* the parts involved in this process.

From what I understand, if I were to call

```
_container.ComposeParts(this);
```

...without providing exports for the `[ImportingConstructor]`s, then none of the parts would be included in the `_container`.

In order to facilitate queries to the container, I have a method as follows:

```
  public Lazy<IEntity> GetPart(Func<Lazy<IEntity, IEntityMetaData>, bool> selector) {
     var entity = _container.GetExports<IEntity, IEntityMetaData>()
                            .Where(selector)
                            .Select(e => e as Lazy<IEntity>)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

     return entity; // this will be passed up to the composition service
  }
```

It seems that `GetExports<T, M>()` will not return an export containing an `[ImportingConstructor]` if the part which would satisfy the dependency is not included in the container.

My approach is to have an extension container/catalog at a low level; a higher level composition service will receive all parts and compose the final object. I decided on this approach so we would be able to add/extend the types of catalogs available in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to satisfy the requirements, I created 3 classes:

```
public sealed class CompositionFactory {
  [Import("Provider")]
  private IProvider importProvider;

  /* MEF initialization */
}

[Export("Provider")]
public sealed class AssemblyProvider : IProvider {
  private CatalogExportProvider _provider;
}

internal sealed class ComposableAggregate { }
```

The `CompositionFactory` initializes MEF to discover the `AssemblyProvider`. When the provider  initializes:

```
private CatalogExportProvider InitializeProvider() {
   // directory catalog
   var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(ExtensionDirectory.FullName);
   return new CatalogExportProvider(dirCatalog);
}
```

...we return a [`CatalogExportProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.catalogexportprovider.aspx). I can now use an API to the CompositionFactory:

```
public ISomething GetSomething(string ContractName, object ContractParam) {
   // implementation
}
```

...to query for the correct composable part using a contract name:

```
public ComposablePartDefinition GetPartDefinition(string ContractName) {
   return _provider.Catalog.Parts
                   .Where(p => p.ExportDefinitions
                                .Select(e => e.ContractName)
                                .Any(c => c == ContractName))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The work is then completed in the ComposableAggregate helper class:

```
internal ISomething Value {
   get {
      return _container.GetExport<IEntity>(_contractName).Value;
   }
}

private CompositionBatch CreateBatch() {
   CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
   // create composable part from definition
   ComposablePart importDef = CreatePart(_contractName);
   batch.AddPart(importDef);
   return batch;
}

private ComposablePart CreatePart(string ContractName) {
   // get part definition from catalog
   return _provider.GetPartDefinition(ContractName).CreatePart();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these concerns are already separated: discovery is handled by catalogs, and composition is done by export providers.

In the typical case, you just pass a catalog directly to the container and for convenience it will automatically take care of creating an [CatalogExportProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.catalogexportprovider.aspx) for it.

But you can also create one or more export providers yourself and pass them to the container with [this constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833626.aspx). (You may also have to set the [SourceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.catalogexportprovider.sourceprovider.aspx) to point back at the container after that, so that the export providers can use each other.)

You can create your own [ExportProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.exportprovider.aspx) implementations, and they don't even have to be backed by catalogs.

Comment: Yes, they are separated - maybe the better term would be independent. We have catalogs that will be extensions to the composition service. Query the service for an entity and a fully composed entity will be returned.

Comment: I think I am going to explore MEF's Convention model. I think it will offer more flexibility in how I want parts discovered.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I just found your blog: http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2011/03/mef-attribute-less-registration.html

Comment: I don't need a custom `ExportProvider` to do this. I will present a very simplified answer shortly - I use the `CatalogExportProvider` in .Net 4.0 rather than composing the container - a la `container.ComposeParts(this)`.