# Passing parameters/properties with MEF

Tags: c#, module, mef, modularity

Consider the following sample:
I have a `Car` class and an `ILogger` interface. I'd like the `ILogger` implementations to log (console, file, db, etc) a list of cars' specs. And of course, I want to use MEF for ILogger. But for logging, my logger class should have access to a car's specification. And I'm not sure what would be the best way to pass objects to my logger classes. To be more clear, here's some code:

```
class Program
{
    public class Car
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }

    private CompositionContainer _container;

    [Import(typeof(ILogger))]
    public ILogger logger;

    private Program()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
        this._container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        this._container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
```

The `ILogger` interface should get a `Car` object for logging. And I'm not sure whether I should pass it in logger's constructor or as a Property, or just a method parameter.

- **Using property**: If I use a property for passing a car, the `ILogger` interface looks like this:

  ```
  public interface ILogger
  {
      Car Car { get; set; }
      void Log();
  }
  ```

  And I can iterate through my list items as below:

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Program p = new Program(); // Composition is performed in the constructor
      var cars = new List()
          {
              new Car() { Brand = "Nissan", Model = "SkyLine" },
              new Car() { Brand = "Porche", Model = "Carrera"},
              new Car() { Brand = "Ferrari", Model = "Enzo"}
          };
      foreach (var car in cars)
      {
          p.logger.Car = car;
          p.logger.Log();
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
  }
  ```
- **Using parameter**:  The interface:

  ```
  public interface ILogger
  {
      void Log(Car car);
  }
  ```

  and the program:

  ```
  foreach (var car in cars)
  {
      p.logger.Log(car);
  }
  ```
- **Using constructor**: This is where I seem to be lost. I can change the `ILogger` interface to :

  ```
  public interface ILogger
  {
      Car Car {get; set;}
      void Log();
  }
  ```

  And in the implemented class:

  ```
  [Export(typeof(ICarLogger))]
  public class ConsoleLogger : ICarLogger
  {
      public Car Car { get; set; }
      [ImportingConstructor]
      public ConsoleLogger(Car car)
      { 
          this.Car = car;
      }
      public void Log()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Brand: {0}\tModel: {1}", Car.Brand, Car.Model);
      }
  }
  ```

**But** this leads to creating the `CompositionContainer` everytime I want to pass a new value to the constructor (By using `ComposeExportedValue` method). Put it simply, How can I pass various variables to the constructor without having to rebuild the whole `CompositionContainer` again?

So, which of these 3 approaches are better in your opinion. And how can I implement the *constructor* approach as mentioned? Hope I described my problem clearly.
Thanks and apologies for the lengthy question.
P.S. I'm using the MEF version which comes with .Net 4.

Comment: Did you want to instantiate a new ILogger for each car? Or, as @blindmeis suggests, an IEnumerable<Car> within the ILogger? I had a similar issue, see my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9626227/210709

Comment: @IAbstract: Please see my comment on blindmeis's reply.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote you wanna log a list of cars, so shouldnt it be:

```
public interface ILogger
{
   void Log(IEnumerable<Car> cars);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the sample was just something to explain my problem about passing parameters.